# Как средствами Pyrogram в Telegram отправить user ботом личное сообщение пользователю в паблике?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pyrogram

Есть пример как отправить пользователю в паблике, есть ли возможность в личную переписку ?

```
    if set(words) & set(element.lower() for element in msg.text.split()):               
       print(f'Найдено Ключевое слово={msg.text}')
       msg.reply(f'{datefunc()}'+' , {0} ! '.format(msg.from_user.first_name) + f'{Hello}')
```

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, пояснить, что вы имеете в виду под чатом и личной перепиской? И разве с ботами не общаются не в отдельной переписке одним человеком?

Comment: Пользователю паблика ответить личным сообщением (лично не в паблике)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.send_message(chat_id=msg.from_user.id,text=f'{datefunc()}' + ' , {0} ! '.format(msg.from_user.first_name) + f'{Hello}')